# Am trying out react with a simple counter. Within the console.log it works perfectly but within the user interface it doesn't update the counter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have code in my Trick.js file as follows:

```
let counter = 0;
const handlesclick = () => {
counter++;console.log("counter", counter)
Trick();
};
export default function Trick() {
return (
 <div>  
 <div>  
 <button onClick={handlesclick}>Increment counter</button>  
 </div>  
 <div>  
      counter value is {counter}  
 </div>  
 </div>  
  )  
}
```

and it is being rendered by index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import Jsx from './Jsx'
import Tools from './Tools';
import Trick from './Trick';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
    <Jsx />
    <Tools name="Ishmo" tool="Adobe"/>
    **<Trick />**
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

The counter in console works perfectly but on user interface it doesn't.
Please help me out

Comment: Use state for maintaining counter. It is react's way of knowing that some change have occurred wrt your component.

ref - https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Trick() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const handlesclick = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
    console.log("counter", counter);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handlesclick}>Increment counter</button>
      </div>
      <div>counter value is {counter}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend reading the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs).

But if you want to create a simply counter, I would build it using the `useState` hook provided by React. Your component would look something like this.

```
export default function Trick() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const handlesClick = () => setCounter(counter + 1);
  return (
    <div>  
      <div>  
        <button onClick={handlesclick}>Increment counter</button>  
      </div>  
      <div>  
        counter value is {counter}  
      </div>  
    </div>  
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the current code is that although the variable may be updating itself, the page rendered the first time containing the value 0, remains the same. What you want to do is trigger a re-render every time the variable changes so that you can “see” the updated value on the page.

You can achieve this by using the useState hook for functional components. You can read more about it in the official docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)
You can refer to the first example in the docs which is a counter app.